# WKWebView: How to local storage enable in iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm trying to local storage enable.
But in iOS8, I can't find how to do it.

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    configuration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.defaultDataStore()
} else {
    //??
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 it seems that local storage is enabled by default.